# Jquery issue with passing function click to function

Tags: recursion, jquery

I would like to push data from mysql db to div every x seconds.

at `window.setTimeout(update, 60000);`  - how to pass in the btnStart.click function into it again???
Not too sure about the syntax for passing in function call.

Here's the code for reference

```
$('#btnStart').click(function() {

$.ajax({

    url: "ajax.php",

    type: "POST",

    data: 'id=6',

    timeout: 15000,

    beforeSend: function(){ 

    },

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#userstatus").html('Timeout contacting server..');
           window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
    },

    success:  function(output) {                            
        output= jQuery.trim(output);
        $('#userstatus').html(output);

        window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
    },

    complete: function(){

    }

});

<div id="userstatus"></div>

<input type="button" id="btnStart" value="start now">
```

Comment: You are missing a `'` after `data='id=6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){$('#btnStart').click();}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will trigger a button click every second:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#btnStart').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Only problem is that the this  should be started after the first click (ok easy to solve). But depending on `success` or `error` the time between the intervals differ...

Comment: setInterval is a good idea, but if let's sa database server got error, it will still ajax call every 30 seconds. Maybe setTimeout written inside btnStart error: longer timeout, success: shorter timeout, would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){update();}, 10000);

function update()
{
    $("#btnStart").trigger("click");
}
```

or you can wrap your ajax call inside another function and invoke that function in the button click and settimeout methods.